# Velocity Eventhandler

Tags: velocity

in velocity, when you do $object.variable if it not be able to find the getter function to 
 access it  or the getter returns a null. it will just show $object.variable explicitly on the page

I know there is a quiet reference, but I don't want to add ! sign to thousands of variables.

I have tried  InvalidReferenceEventHandler, NullValueHandler they all didn't get called.

I wander is there a specific type of Eventhandler for this.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

The above seems to be a valid choice as well.  However here is another option:

```
public class AppSpecificInvalidReferenceEventHandler implements 
                                                     InvalidReferenceEventHandler
{

  private static final Logger LOGGER = 
     Logger.getLogger(AppSpecificInvalidReferenceEventHandler.class);

  @Override
  public Object invalidGetMethod(Context context, String reference, 
                                 Object object, String property, Info info)
  {
    reportInvalidReference(reference, info);
    return "";
  }

  @Override
  public boolean invalidSetMethod(Context context, String leftreference, 
                                  String rightreference, Info info)
  {
    reportInvalidReference(leftreference, info);
    return false;
  }

  @Override
  public Object invalidMethod(Context context, String reference, Object object, 
                              String method, Info info)
  {
    if (reference == null) {
      reportInvalidReference(object.getClass().getName() + "." + method, info);
    } else {
      reportInvalidReference(reference, info);
    }
    return "";
  }

  private void reportInvalidReference(String reference, Info info)
  {
    LOGGER.info("REFRERENCE: " + reference + " Info <" + info + ">");
  }
}
```

You'll also need to add the following to your velocity.properties file:

```
eventhandler.invalidreferences.class=path.to.package.AppSpecificInvalidReferenceEventHandler,org.apache.velocity.app.event.implement.ReportInvalidReferences
```

You might be surprised at the results though, so it will likely need fine-tuning dependent upon your needs.

Comment: still not working scott, I am still trying to find a answer, will get you updated.

Comment: Whaat behavior did you see with the above code? I tested it in our application and indeed had the invalid references not show up on the rendered page. Are you sure your properties were picked up. Add any logging to the example?

Answer (score 2):

I'm basing this off of Engine-1.7 code.

It seems that when an invalid method is called that the utility method EventHandlerUtil.invalidGetMethod is called.  This method creates a new InvalidGetMethodExecutor (this is an inner class on InvalidReferenceEventHandler).  Eventually this chains down into a call to invalidReferenceHandlerCall which eventually iterates over any handlerIterators which have been defined.  Unfortunately I don't know enough about the internals of Velocity to tell you how to inject these values though.  My guess is that the user list will suggest a way to override this behavior or a suggestion will be to use / implement a custom tool.

Edit:

According to the Developer Guide you can do the following.  You'll need to write some code to deal with it, but it shouldn't be too difficult:

Pluggable Introspection

```
runtime.introspector.uberspect = org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.UberspectImpl
```

This property sets the 'Uberspector', the introspection package that handles all introspection strategies for Velocity. You can specify a comma-separated list of Uberspector classes, in which case all Uberspectors are chained. The default chaining behaviour is to return the first non-null value for each introspection call among all provided uberspectors. You can modify this behaviour (for instance to restrict access to some methods) by subclassing org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.AbstractChainableUberspector (or implementing directly org.apache.velocity.util.introspection.ChainableUberspector). This allows you to create more interesting rules or patterns for Uberspection, rather than just returning the first non-null value.

Comment: In most of my cases the getter itself is valid, however the value which the getter returns might be null, that's the hard bit, because the method is valid , the invalid st ethos never gets called

Comment: The same code is basically traversed if the reference is null (The call to execute returns null when the getter doesn't exist -- unless you have turned on strict references).

Comment: how to turn on strict ref? do you mean not using quiet reference? but still thanks a lot mate for your time and kindness.