# How to retrieve invalid references from Velocity Engine?

Tags: velocity

I am wondering if there is a way to retrieve a list of invalid references in Velocity after calling VelocityEngine.evaluate.

[Velocity Eventhandler](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7649289/velocity-eventhandler) has some nice information about creating an **AppSpecificInvalidReferenceEventHandler** which I have used in the VelocityEngine as follows.

```
<bean id="templateVelocityEngine" class="org.springframework.ui.velocity.VelocityEngineFactoryBean">
    <property name="velocityProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="resource.loader">class</prop>
            <prop key="class.resource.loader.class">org.apache.velocity.runtime.resource.loader.ClasspathResourceLoader</prop>
            <prop key="class.resource.loader.cache">true</prop>         
            <prop key="eventhandler.invalidreferences.class">xyz.util.AppSpecificInvalidReferenceEventHandler,org.apache.velocity.app.event.implement.ReportInvalidReferences</prop>
        </props>
    </property>     
</bean>
```

After velocity's evaluate call, I see the log statements showing that AppSpecificInvalidReferenceEventHandler is working, but I can't see how to retrieve that class and it's List of InvalidReferenceInfo if I declare the *eventhandler.invalidreferences.class* in the Spring context as above.

Populating and evaluating the template looks like the following :-

```
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
StringWriter bodyWriter = new StringWriter();

context.put("body", "some body text!");

boolean result = templateVelocityEngine.evaluate(context, bodyWriter, "logTag", "template ${body} text here loaded from a file");
```

So I would like to do something like the following (except ec.getInvalidReferenceEventHandlers() is null)

```
EventCartridge ec = context.getEventCartridge();
Iterator it = ec.getInvalidReferenceEventHandlers();

while (it.hasNext()) {
    Object obj = it.next();

    if (obj instanceof ReportInvalidReferences) {
        AppSpecificInvalidReferenceEventHandler handler = (AppSpecificInvalidReferenceEventHandler) obj;
        List invalidRefs = handler.getInvalidReferences();

        if (!invalidRefs.isEmpty()) {
            // process the list of invalid references here
        }
    }
}
```

The only way around this I've found so far is to not declare *eventhandler.invalidreferences.class* in the Spring bean i.e. instead I would do the following

```
ReportInvalidReferences reporter = new AppSpecificInvalidReferenceEventHandler();
EventCartridge ec = new EventCartridge();
ec.addEventHandler(reporter);
ec.attachToContext(context);
VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
StringWriter bodyWriter = new StringWriter();

context.put("body", "some body text!");

boolean result = templateVelocityEngine.evaluate(context, bodyWriter, "logTag", "template ${body} text here loaded from a file");
```

With the additional pre Velocity evaluate setup code above (and commenting the *eventhandler.invalidreferences.class* in the Spring bean), I can then call

```
ec.getInvalidReferenceEventHandlers();
```

And I get back the AppSpecificInvalidReferenceEventHandler in the Iterator returned...